# (book example) Why is char* argv[argc+1] returning an error?

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C through the book Modern C by Jens Gustedt. In it is the following example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* lower and upper iteration limits centered around 1.0 */
static double const eps1m01 = 1.0 - 0x1P-01;
static double const eps1p01 = 1.0 + 0x1P-01;
static double const eps1m24 = 1.0 - 0x1P-24;
static double const eps1p24 = 1.0 + 0x1P-24;

int main (int argc, char* argv[argc+1]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) { // process args
        double const a = strtod(argv[i], 0); // arg -> double
        double x = 1.0;
        for (;;) { // by powers of 2
            double prod = a * x;
            if (prod < eps1m01) {
                x *= 2.0;
            }
            else if (eps1p01 < prod) {
                x *= 0.5;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("x: %f \n", x);
        for (;;) { // Heron approximation
            double prod = a * x;
            if ((prod < eps1m24) || (eps1p24 < prod)) {
                x *= (2.0 - prod);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    
        printf("heron: a = % .5e, \tx = % .5e, \ta * x = % .12f\n",
               a, x, a * x);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm using visual studio to follow along and this

```
char* argv[argc+1]
```

gives me an error at argc+1, I removed it and it seems to work, but I'd like to know if this is in anyway changing what the program does/ if this is just an antiquated way of writing the argument

Comment: If `argc == 2`, you have two arguments (and two elements of the `argv[]` array are filed (the third contains `NULL`)). Arrays in C are indexed `0` to `n - 1`. So for an array with two elements, the valid indexes are `0` and `1`. `argv[argc + 1]` is one past the `NULL` entry which is an invalid address. The first entry is the program name being run. So if you pass 1 argument, the `argv` array of pointers will contain `"prog name"`, `"1st arg"`, `NULL` at indexes `0`, `1`, `2`. `argc + 1` would be `3` (an invalid index)

Comment: The proper declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). You don't put anything between the `[..]` with `argv` in the declaration of `main()` itself. See [C18 Standard - §5.1.2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.5.1.2) (under 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup, specifically) *See also* [**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Comment: Surprisingly, gcc 10.2.1 didn't complain about `char *argv[argc+1]` and the assembler code is identical for `char **argv`.  Only `-Wvla` makes it complain.

Comment: Not sure, but do you want to reset `x` as `1.0` before going into the second loop? There's some unknown-to-me strangeness to this code. (I'm antiquated!) `static` buys you nothing for a single source file. And, 1 = 1, so there's no need for `0x1` in those initialisations... The indenting is not 'conventional'... A difficult read...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, how `char *argv[argc]` can be different from `char *argv[]`? They both are transformed to to `char**` when the type of the function is inferred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int main (int argc, char* argv[argc+1])` declares the `argv` parameter as a *variable length array* (VLA).

Variable length arrays are an optional feature of C. Compilers don't have to support it. MSVC does not support it. Other major compilers do.

This declaration of `main` does not conform to the standard at all. The standard allows two forms of `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) // note no size in brackets
int main(void)
```

Other functions can have VLA arguments but `main` cannot.

So it is an error in the book. Remove the size between the brackets and all should be well.

Comment: I don't think it is a mistake. The C spec says that it should be equivalent to the declarations above. Read  https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1 carefully. The type `int(int, char*[*])` is compatible with `int(int, char*[])` and `int(int, char**)`

Comment: @tstanisl The standard doesn't talk about the type of `main`, but about the form of the declaration (which is IMHO stupid but it is what it is).

Comment: I know it is poorly written. It just says " or equivalent". IMO the declaration from the book *is equivalent* thus correct.

Comment: @tstanisl It is not entirely clear what is meant by "equivalent" here. If implementations are allowed to reject one declaration but not the other, are they equivalent? I would say no. The standard could have said "the type of the first parameter shall be be `int`, and the type of the second parameter shall be `char**` after array-to-pointer adjustment, if any". But it didn't say that.